# Collision issue when player moves from one object to another

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

In unity 5 I am having an issue with certain collisions. I made a basic maze-like game where the player controls a cube across platforms (made from other cubes). In certain areas, two or more of the platforms touch so the player can get to different areas of the level. The problem with my collision happens at these intersections. The player will seem to get stuck for no reason and they would have to back up and get a running start in order to get to the other platform. I went through everything and made sure they are lined up perfectly in the unity editor but nothing seems to fix this.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated .

EDIT: all of my objects are using box colliders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common (and good) practice is to **use a Circle collider on the bottom of your character object** in conjunction with a Box collider.

For Example:
[image]

While this will likely fix your issue, the source of the problem is probably using many small tiled cubes each with their own colliders. A large amount of tiled objects with colliders most likely cause performance and collision issues.